# Adding a dynamic erb tag in a <span> not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, html

I'm trying to include a erb tag in my span tag as followed:

```
<span  style="width:' +<% @completion %>''%'"></span>
```

but it doesn't work. Anyone knows how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to output the returned value of `@completion`, in erb you can achieve that by doing this:

```
# with an equal sign:
<span><%= "Hello!" %></span>
# but the following will not output "hello"
<span><% "Hello!" %></span>
       #^ no equal sign -> not displayed
```

**In your case:**

```
<span style="width: <%= @completion %>%;"></span>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Many Thanks MrYoshiji! Works like a charm!